# Show a non intrusive message to the user

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm making a eclipse plugin and I was wondering is there any way I could display a message to the user which they do not need to dismiss?

Something like a message dialog but they do not need to press ok.

Comment: Eclipse has a status bar at the bottom.  Perhaps you could write your message on the status bar?

Comment: Depends on where the user is and how important the message is. For dialogs Gregs answer is the best. Status bar is very easy to miss. I'd say print it as an info log. This will end up in the error log as an info.

Answer (score 1):

In a view you can set a message in the status line at the bottom of the Eclipse window with:

```java
getViewSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager().setMessage(msg);
```

in an editor you can do something similar:

```java
getEditorSite().getActionBars().getStatusLineManager().setMessage(msg);
```

If you want to show messages when you are displaying a popup dialog use `TitleAreaDialog` which has an area at the top of the dialog for messages.